# Permutation of phone numbers starting at button x, ending at button y, and z numbers long

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation

I am trying find the total number of permutations possible with a given x, y, and z. 
x is the initial number, y is the final number, and z is the total number of buttons pressed.
I am supposed to only move from number to number like the knight in chess, in an 'L' shape.
For example, if you just dialed a 1, the next number you dial has to be either a 6 or an 8. If you just dialed a 6, the next number must be a 1 or 7. 
Currently, my implementation outputs the correct answer for all the numbers I have given it. However, it is **god awful slow** because compute time is exponential. What I want to know is how I can compute this in linear time, more or less. z will always be between 1 and 100, inclusive.

```
##Computes the number of phone numbers one
##can dial that start with the digit x, end
##in the digit y, and consist of z digits in
##total. Output this number as a
##string representing the number in base-10.
##Must follow "knights rule" moves, like chess
##########_________##########
##########|1||2||3|##########
##########|_||_||_|##########
##########|4||5||6|##########
##########|_||_||_|##########
##########|7||8||9|##########
##########|_||_||_|##########
##########|_||0||_|##########
##########^^^^^^^^^##########
dict = {0: [4, 6], 1: [6, 8], 2: [7, 9], 3: [4, 8],
    4: [0, 3, 9], 5: [], 6: [0, 1, 7], 7: [2, 6], 8: [1, 3],
    9: [2, 4]}


def recAnswer(current, y, z, count, total):
    if count == z and current == y:
            total += 1
            return total
    count+=1
    if count > z:
            return total
    for i in dict.get(current):
            total = recAnswer(i, y, z, count, total)
    return total

def answer(x, y, z):
    if x == y:
            if z%2 == 0:
                    return '0'
    elif x == 5 or y == 5:
            if z == 1 and x == y:
                    return '1'
            else:
                    return '0'
    elif x%2 != 0 and y%2 == 0:
            if z%2 != 0:
                    return '0'
    elif x%2 == 0 and y%2 != 0:
            if z%2 != 0:
                    return '0'
    elif x%2 == 0 and y%2 ==0:
            if z%2 == 0:
                    return '0'
    elif x%2 != 0 and y%2 != 0:
            if z%2 == 0:
                    return '0'

    total = recAnswer(x,y,z,1,0)
    return str(total)

def test():
    for i in xrange(1,15,1):
            print i,":",answer(1,3,i)

    print answer(6, 2, 5)
    print answer(1, 6, 3)
    print answer(1, 1, 99)


test()
```

Comment: This is better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com because you aren't facing any issues, but just need tips on improving your code.

Comment: Better suites codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Noted! I will ask there.

Comment: @l3li3l I've got some draft written for a quicker implementation... Is there an existing implementation to test the results?

Comment: [Same question on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/71988/permutation-of-phone-numbers-starting-at-button-x-ending-at-button-y-and-z-num)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that your code is slow is that you end up visiting (and recalculating) the same combinations over and over again. You can cut the recalculation part short with a technique called memoization.

Memoization is easy to add, but let's redesign your recursive function so that the calling function does the accumulation, not the function itself. In other words, don't pass the total and return the combinations of this subpath only:

```
def recAnswer(current, y, z, count):
    if count == z and current == y:
        return 1

    count += 1
    if count > z:
        return 0

    total = 0
    for i in dict.get(current):
        total += recAnswer(memo, i, y, z, count)

    return total
```

This change doesn't change the calculation itself; the results are still the same.

Now let's cut all repeated calls to the same arguments short. we pass a dictionary `memo` to the function. The keys to this dict are tuples of your function arguments. As first step in the recursive function, check whether the calculation has already been done. As last step of the initial calculation, add the solution to the dict:

```
def recAnswer(memo, current, y, z, count):
    # dict key is the tuple of arguments
    key = (current, y, z, count)

    # Have we been here before? If so, return memoized answer
    if key in memo:
        return memo[key]

    if count == z and current == y:
        return 1

    count += 1
    if count > z:
        return 0

    total = 0
    for i in dict.get(current):
        total += recAnswer(memo, i, y, z, count)

    # Store answer for later use
    memo[key] = total

    return total
```

And get the calculation underway with an empty dict, of course:

```
total = recAnswer({}, x, y, z, 1)
```

**Addendum:** Now that I have learned about `@decorator`s, I'll decorate the function with memoization so that the original function is not changed. Well, I'm going to make one more change, as Janne mentioned in the comments: I'll coalesce the target cound and current count into one variable, the count which starts at the target value and counts down to zero instead up to the target value.

First, the memoization decorator, which will be a class that holds the function to decorate, `func` and the memoization dictionary. This class must implement a functon `__call__` with the desired number of arguments:

```
class memoized(object):
    """Decorator function that adds the memoization"""

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.memo = {}

    def __call__(self, current, target, count): 
        key = (current, target, count)
        if key not in self.memo:
            self.memo[key] = self.func(current, target, count)
        return self.memo[key]
```

And now the simplified function with the decorator before the `def`inition:

```
@memoized
def recAnswer(current, target, count):
    """Unmemoized original function"""

    if count == 0:
        return int(current == target)       # False: 0, True: 1

    total = 0
    for next in dict[current]:
        total += recAnswer(next, target, count - 1)

    return total
```

The `@memoized` decorator calls the function `recAnswer` through `memoized.__call__`, which handles the memoization. Call the recursive function like this:

```
total = recAnswer(x, y, z - 1)
```

(The -1 here takes into account that in the original code, counting starts at 1.)

There is probably still room for improvement. For example, you could make the number of arguments for the `memoized` decorator class variable with the splat syntax, so that you can re-use the memoizer for other functions:

```
def __call__(self, *args): 
    if args not in self.memo:
        self.memo[args] = self.func(*args)
    return self.memo[args]
```

The upshot of all this is that if you have a problem where you re-evaluate the same set of parameters again and again, simply keeping track of previously calculated results can give you a tremendous speed-up without having to fiddle with the basic implementation.

Comment: You can also implement memoization with a `@decorator`, rather than make the dictionary an argument.

Comment: You could get rid of `count` variable and just use `z-1` in the recursive call. Besides simplifying the code, this would make the memo useful for evaluating different `z` with same `y`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Good point, thanks. I didn't know about decorators. Now I do. I've added a decorator variant to the post.

Comment: Happy to help; `memoize` is pretty much the canonical example of a decorator (not including `property`, I suppose), and I'm sure you'll find them very useful!

Comment: @JanneKarila: You're right, counting down both feels more natural and is more efficient for "global" memoization. But in the original answer I didn't want to deviate too much from the OP's code. I've incorporated your suggestion in my addendum, though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

from [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/71988/permutation-of-phone-numbers-starting-at-button-x-ending-at-button-y-and-z-num)

```
"""Solve the phone/chess paths problem from this question:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/71988
"""

# Move dictionary
MOVES = {0: [4, 6],
         1: [6, 8],
         2: [7, 9],
         3: [4, 8],
         4: [0, 3, 9],
         5: [],
         6: [0, 1, 7],
         7: [2, 6],
         8: [1, 3],
         9: [2, 4]}

# Cache implementation
def cache(func):
    """Standard cache decorator implementation."""
    cache_dct = {}
    def wrapper(*args):
        if args not in cache_dct:
            cache_dct[args] = func(*args)
        return cache_dct[args]
    return wrapper

# Recusive function 
@cache
def rec(x, y, z):
    """Recursively count the number of path
    to go from x to y in z moves.
    """
    if not z:
        return int(x == y)
    return sum(rec(x, y, z-1) for x in MOVES[x])

# Paths function
def paths(x, y, z):
    """Count the number of paths to go from x to y
    with z key strokes.
    """
    if not z:
        return 0
    return rec(x, y, z-1)

# Main execution
if __name__ == "__main__":
    example = "paths(1, 1, 99)"
    print example + " = " + str(eval(example))
    # Output: paths(1, 1, 99) = 30810672576979228350316940764381184
```